# Connect to SQL Server with Management Studio using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-authentication

I am working with Management studio and I want to log in to databases located on another server in another domain. The only login I have for such is with Windows credentials.

I want to be able to log in via Management Studio on my local PC. I have found the only way to do so is using a command similar to:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Progr...\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

While this works, it isn't the easiest or nicest way. Is there a better way? Any way I can do it within Management Studio?

Comment: Is "another server" in a different domain? If so, then how you're doing it is how you do it (other than establishing an RDP session and opening SSMS on the other server).

Comment: If I were you I would create a shortcut to the command you have listed.  Call it `SSMS Domain` or something similar.  That way you hide the command and it will look very similar to the normal SSMS shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only elegant ways to connect to a SQL Server in another domain but still use Windows Authentication are:

- What you're already doing: `runas /netonly`
- Connecting via remote desktop and opening SSMS locally on the remote server

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers you've received, you can also shift-right click on an executable or a shortcut to one and in the resulting context menu, there should be an option to run as a different user. I tried this on my Win 7 machine. I seem to recall that in XP, I had to install [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) for these options to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a graphical password prompt by downloading [ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) or better yet, the entire [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).

- Store the executable(s) for ShellRunAs or the Sysinternals Suite in a location of your choice. I recommend:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Sysinternals
  ```
- You can then enable a "Run as different user..." context menu option for all applications/shortcuts by running

  ```
  shellrunas /reg
  ```

  [image: Run as different user]
- If you want to only enable this for SQL Server Management Studio, you can create a shortcut to it and pass the path the management studio like so:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\Sysinternals\ShellRunas.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
  ```

If you download the entire Sysinternal Suite, I would recommend you [add the directory to your PATH environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Please note that you will need to adjust the paths above based on your SQL Server Management Studio version and whether you're running 64 bit or 32 bit Windows.